# Crawled but not scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape using Scrapy the following website ([https://www.leadhome.co.za/search/property-for-sale/western-cape/4?sort=date'](https://www.leadhome.co.za/search/property-for-sale/western-cape/4?sort=date%27)), and I see that the page gets crawled but none of the items are returned. Everything works withing Scrapy Shell.

Here is the code I have:

```
class LeadHomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lead_home"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.leadhome.co.za/search/property-for-sale/western-cape/4?sort=date',
    ]

    # parse search page
    def parse(self, response):
        # follow property link
        offering = 'buy' if 'sale' in response.css('h1::text').get() else 'rent'
        for prop in response.css('div.search__PropertyCardWrapper-sc-1j5dndx-0.bsqBpI'):
            link = 'https://www.leadhome.co.za' + prop.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            a = prop.css('p.styles__Label-h53xsw-16.bcSkCI::text').getall()
            #prop_type = attempt_get_property_type(a[0]) if len(a) != 0 else None
            area = a[1] if len(a) > 1 else None

            yield scrapy.Request(
                link,
                meta={'item': {
                    'agency': self.name,
                    'url': link,
                    'area': area,
                    'offering': offering,
                    #'property_type': prop_type,
                }},
                callback=self.parse_property,
            )

        # follow to next page
        next_page_number = response.xpath(
            '//a[contains(@class, "styles__PageNumber-zln67a-0 jRCKhp")]/following-sibling::a/text()').get()
        if next_page_number is not None:
            new_page_link = 'https://www.leadhome.co.za/search/property-for-sale/western-cape/4?sort=date&page=' + next_page_number
            next_page = response.urljoin(new_page_link)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    # parse property
    def parse_property(self, response):
        item = response.meta.get('item')
        item['parking'] = response.xpath('//p[contains(text(), "Uncovered Parking:")]/following-sibling::p/text()').get()
   
...
```

Any idea what might be wrong here? Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using **random** class values (`1j5dndx-0.bsqBpI` etc) in your CSS expressions that's why your code don't work. Here is the same code but using XPath's `contains` to match a part of a class:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # follow property link
    offering = 'buy' if 'sale' in response.css('h1::text').get() else 'rent'
    # for prop in response.css('div.search__PropertyCardWrapper-sc-1j5dndx-0.bsqBpI'):
    for prop in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "search__PropertyCardWrapper-sc-")]'):
        link = prop.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
        # a = prop.css('p.styles__Label-h53xsw-16.bcSkCI::text').getall()
        prop_type = prop.xpath('(.//p[contains(@class, "styles__Label-")])[1]/text()').get()
        # area = a[1] if len(a) > 1 else None

        link = response.urljoin(link)
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=link,
            meta={'item': {
                'agency': self.name,
                'url': link,
                # 'area': area,
                'offering': offering,
                'property_type': prop_type,
            }},
            callback=self.parse_property,
        )
```